# Enviar parâmetro de uma rota para outra

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-rotas

Quero enviar uma variável de uma rota para outra, para exibir essa variável na view, exemplo de uso:

```
public function create(ExamRequest $request)
{
    Exam::create( $request->all() );
    $message = 'A avaliação "'.$request->input('name').'" foi registrada!';
    return redirect()->route('exams')->withMessage($message);
}
```

A rota `exams` no meu caso chama uma `view`, e tento exibir o parâmetro na mesma assim:

```
<div class="row text-success text-center">
    {{ isset($message) ? $message : '' }}
</div>
```

Mas nunca é exibido nada, como eu consigo enviar um parâmetro para outra rota?

**PS:** sei que com *view* funciona, exemplo `view('exams')->withMessage($message);`, mas no caso não altera o link do navegador, e quero que esse link se atere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há nada de errado com seu redirecionamento.

Na verdade, o método `with`¹ armazena o valor passado temporariamente na sessão, até que o mesmo seja acessado. Isso se chama "Session Flash" na maioria dos frameworks.

<sub>1 - Tanto na chamada normal do método como na chamada mágica do método with os dados são enviados para o flash</sub>

Para acessar o valor, você teria que fazer assim na view:

```
 {!! session('message') !!}
```

Comment: Não gosto da forma convencional.

Comment: Embora eu use as vezes.

Comment: Tirei o "convencional" porque ficou meio estranho. Na verdade, o Laravel tem mil jeito de usar a mesma função, kkkkkkkkk

Comment: Tem nada. Deve ter menos de 10.

Comment: `with([flash' => $message])`, `with('flash', $message)`, `withFlash($message)`, `session()->flash('flash', $message)`, `session()->flash(['flash' => $message])` ... cansei...

Comment: Então, aí tem 5...

Answer (score 2):

```
return redirect()->route('exams')->with(['message' => $message]);
```

Se estiver configurado no arquivo de routes uma ação para o link **exams**, vai dar certo.

```
<div class="row text-success text-center">
    {!! (Session::has('message')) ? Session::get('message') : '' !!}
</div>
```